# Large JSON Storage

Tags: json, server, scaling, database-performance, query-performance

### Summary

What is the "best practice" way to store large JSON arrays on a remote web service?

### Background

I've got a service, "service A", that generates JSON objects, an "item", no larger than 1KiB. Every time it emits an item, the item needs to be appended to a JSON array. Later, a user can get all these arrays of items, which can be 10s of MiB or more.

### Performance

What is the best way to store JSON to make appending and retrieval performant? Ideally, insertation would be O(1) and retrieval would be fast enough that we didn't need to tell the user to wait until their files have downloaded.

The downloads have never become so large that the constraint is the time to download them from the server (if they were a 10 MiB file). The constraint has always been the time to compute the file.

### Stack

Our current stack is running Django + Postgresql on Elasticbeanstalk. New services are acceptable (e.g. S3 if append were supported).

### Attempted Solutions

1. When we try to store all JSON in a single row in the database, performance is understandably slow.
2. When we try to store each JSON object in a separate row, it takes too long to aggregate the separate rows into a single array of items. In addition, a user requests all item arrays in their account every time they visit the main screen of the app, so it is inefficient to recompute the aggregated array of items each time.

Comment: You could put them in Mongodb. One thing you might consider is to store each Json object separately and only construct them into an array when they are requested.

Comment: Actually you will likely have performance issues inserting into large arrays in with mongodb. If it were me I would construct the array on request not store as array.

Comment: You say "In addition, a user requests all item arrays in their account every time they visit the main screen of the app" I think you might want to consider the implications of downloading a 10MiB json array every time you visit a web page. That is going to be a problem no matter how fast your db solution is.

Comment: @bhspencer The time to download hasn't been a problem. It's always been the time to compute them.

Comment: @Will yes but the problem is expecting a client that visits your site to waste that much bandwidth. Also _you_ waste that much bandwidth, which incurs costs. Consider using the [`IndexedDB` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) and only sending the changes required to synchronize the client with the server whenever the client goes back to the page.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts A 0.5-1.5s download every time our clients open a dashboard is acceptable. Our problem is that this download takes not 0.5-1.5s, as it would if it were a static file, but several seconds.

Comment: @Will what you are proposing to do, download 10MiB of json on page load, is in opposition to common practice. I suppose it is possible that you have got it right and almost everyone else has it wrong but I suspect that is not the the case.

Comment: @Will that is false. You can't think of your server's performance as the bottleneck. The client is also a bottleneck, and if they're running on dial-up, you're looking at an upwards of 10-15 seconds for 10 MiB

Comment: You're right: they could both be bottlenecks, but right now the **bottleneck**—the narrowest point in the pipeline—is not the client.